# Why is an implicit string conversion for `${URL}` so much slower than `${URL.toString()}` in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance

All references to the variable `url` in the question are an instance of URL.

I was trying to test `new URL(url)` or `new URL(url.toString())` would be faster since it's in a fairly hot code path. The latter came out way faster and after some digging I found out that it's because the [Node.js implementation of URL](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/8bc6e193a07613a29eaf30d609f3c6d20db94031/lib/internal/url.js#L734) has a line that converts the input to a string with a template string literal.

I benched just the template string conversion against converting it to a string beforehand with `toString` and the latter was about 6x faster in Node and 2x faster in Firefox.

Why is interpolating a URL object into a template string directly drastically slower than interpolating its string representation obtained through `URL.toString`, even though both of those give the same output?

Comment: Your title and body actually refer to 2 different things, please clarify what you are asking for?

Comment: Why is interpolating a URL object into a template string drastically slower than interpolating its string representation obtained through URL.toString? Isn't the template string calling the same method under the hood as well?

Comment: @NayanGautam Please [edit] your question to refer to either `url.toString()` or `url.href`, not to both

Comment: @NayanGautam: The compiler could easily special-case the "already a string" case, and given that that particular template string is nothing *but* that single value, it could effectively be optimizing all the work away. I'm not about to march through the JIT-generated code to figure out what it actually does, but it's not unreasonable to think `input = \`${input}\`;` might be compiled to `if (typeof input !== "string") { let b = Builder(); b.append(input.toString()); input = b.toString(); }`, doing nothing but a type check when already a string, while adding more overhead to non-string case.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, sorry I should've made that clearer. Updated the question.

Comment: Could you also include your benchmark tests so we can  check the same thing?